# An error occurred (InvalidParameterException) when calling the DetectDocumentText operation: Request has invalid parameters

Tags: amazon-textract

Textract detect_document_text method from boto3 package is erroring out in my local machine only on images of a certain size. It responds with a super cryptic message, so I am at a loss how to debug this further. The [documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/textract.html#Textract.Client.detect_document_text) doesn't indicate that there are any other parameters that I can pass through.

I am attempting to pass the image bytes directly to the method call

```py
client.detect_document_text(
  Document={
    'Bytes': img,
  }
)
```

Variable `img` is a bytes array `img = b'...'` and of size `len(img) == 22023165`. The image is 2.4 MB.

Comment: 22023165 is not 2.4 MB, it's more like 22 MB.

Comment: Right. When I save the image to a file, it is only 2.4 MB. Maybe this is something poppler is doing (pdf2image) to inflate the image after being converted to a PDF